# Periodic orbit attracts an open set of initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> We have and ode $x'=f(x)$, where   $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function.
>
> Suppose that $\gamma$ is a periodic orbit for this ode.
>
> Suppose also that there exists $y \in \mathbb{R}^2 $, $y \notin \gamma$, such that
>   $\omega(y) = \gamma$ (it means that $\gamma$ is a limit cycle).
>
> Prove that there exist an open set U in  $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\forall z \in U$, $\omega(z) = \gamma$.

I tried to use Poincaré Bendixson theorem and continuity of solutions with respect to initial conditions in order to prove that such $U$ exists.
I couldn't see a clear way to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it is a very good approach. The only problem is that the fact that for all the points on (one side of) a transversal their $\omega$-limit set is just the limit cycle is (usually) hidden in a proof.